# scrollIntoView съедает следующий клик

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка

Есть кастомный дропдаун (вообще на реакте, но это не важно).

Когда input получает фокус, отображается выпадающий блок и делается подписка на capturing-стадию клика по документу. В этом обработчике проверяется, клик произошёл внутри области, или вне. Если вне, то дропдаун закрывается, а обработчик снимается.

Так всё работает. Проблема возникает при добавлении в код `inp.scrollIntoView()` или ручном изменении `scrollTop` контейнера: если следующий клик происходит по аналогичному интупу, то обработчик клика вообще не вызывается.

> [image: скринвидео]

Функции вызываются как-то так:

```
focus #1 #1
focus #2 #2
click #1
close #1
click #2
close #2
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2qb5L7og/1/

```js
for (let inp of document.querySelectorAll("input")) {
  inp.addEventListener('focus', e => {
    console.log("focus", e.target.value, inp.value)
    
    var dd = inp.nextElementSibling

    dd.style.display = 'block'
    inp.scrollIntoView()

    document.addEventListener('click', function close(e) {
      console.log("click", inp.value)
      
      if (e.target.closest("section") !== inp.parentElement) {
        console.log("close", inp.value)
      
        dd.style.display = ''
        document.removeEventListener('click', close, true)
      }
    }, true)
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 11.4em;
  overflow: auto;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 1em 7em 1em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #8FF;
}

input {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <input value="#1" readonly>
    <div>In #1<br>In #1<br>In #1<br>In #1</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input value="#2" readonly>
    <div>In #2<br>In #2<br>In #2<br>In #2</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input value="#3" readonly>
    <div>In #3<br>In #3<br>In #3<br>In #3</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input value="#4" readonly>
    <div>In #4<br>In #4<br>In #4<br>In #4</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input value="#5" readonly>
    <div>In #5<br>In #5<br>In #5<br>In #5</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Если заменить событие `focus` на `click`, то работать будет нормально.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, `focus` ещё tab'ом получается... Впрочем, в этом месте другой косяк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже из-за того, что в момент клика двигается контент, отпуск клавиши мышки происходит в другом месте, что браузером не интерпретируется, как событие `click`.

Я вижу два решения:

- Поставить задержку прокрутки.
- Использовать событие `mousedown`.

Пример с событием `mousedown`.

```js
for (let inp of document.querySelectorAll("input")) {
  inp.addEventListener('focus', e => {
    console.log("focus", e.target.value, inp.value)

    var dd = inp.nextElementSibling

    dd.style.display = 'block'
    inp.scrollIntoView()

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function close(e) {
      console.log("click", inp.value)

      if (e.target.closest("section") !== inp.parentElement) {
        console.log("close", inp.value)

        dd.style.display = ''
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', close, true)
      }
    }, true)
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 11.4em;
  overflow: auto;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 1em 7em 1em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #8FF;
}

input {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <input value="#1" readonly>
    <div>In #1<br>In #1<br>In #1<br>In #1</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input value="#2" readonly>
    <div>In #2<br>In #2<br>In #2<br>In #2</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input value="#3" readonly>
    <div>In #3<br>In #3<br>In #3<br>In #3</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input value="#4" readonly>
    <div>In #4<br>In #4<br>In #4<br>In #4</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input value="#5" readonly>
    <div>In #5<br>In #5<br>In #5<br>In #5</div>
  </section>
</main>
```